# Type refinement not working with instanceof

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following code:

```
function getBar(foo : mixed) {
  if (foo instanceof HTMLElement) {
    return foo.bar;
  }
}

function getBar2(foo : HTMLElement) {
  return foo.bar2;
}
```

`getBar` passes, while `getBar2` fails...

```
10:   return foo.bar2;
                 ^ property `bar2`. Property not found in
10:   return foo.bar2;
             ^ HTMLInputElement
```

Surely both of these should fail the type check?

According to the docs, [an instanceof check should refine the type](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#a-instanceof-b) of `foo` in this case, no?

Comment: Definitely looks wrong. It works if you replace `mixed` with one of the parent classes of `HTMLElement` (`Element`, `Node`, `EventTarget`), but not `Object`, for some reason. I would submit it to https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues